# c# - How can I extract a FAT Disk Image?

Tags: c#, fat, diskimage

I am actually trying to extract a Fat Disk Image with DiskUtils but I am not getting the correct file names...

I get "\TURNER~3\TOPPER~1.P~1" in place of "\TURNEROVER\TOPPERSHEATH.PPTX"

```
FatFileSystem FatImg = new FatFileSystem(MS); //MS = Fat Image MemoryStream
foreach(DiscDirectoryInfo Di in FatImg.Root.GetDirectories())
{
    foreach(DiscFileInfo Fi in Di.GetFiles())
    {
        Stream St = Fi.OpenRead(); // Correct Stream
        string FName = Fi.Name; //Wrong Name
    }
}
```

This is because DiscUtils does not support LFN [Long File Names]...

So I am looking for a perfect library to extract these files befor i try to make one myself...

Is there any way I can Extract it [maybe by DiscUtils] without FileName Errors...

Comment: Do you have an existing FAT image file somewhere, we can play with?

Comment: Get the [Sample Fat Image](http://www.mediafire.com/?qbnjw7d3c77er15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some modifications that you can add to `DiscUtils` to support `FAT LFN`s:

First, make these changes to the `Fat\Directory.cs` file, like this (you need to add the `_lfns` variable, the `GetLfnChunk` function, and modify the existing `LoadEntries` function to add the lines marked with `//+++` below):

```
internal Dictionary<string, string> _lfns = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

private static string GetLfnChunk(byte[] buffer)
{
    // see http://home.teleport.com/~brainy/lfn.htm
    // NOTE: we assume ordinals are ok here.
    char[] chars = new char[13];
    chars[0] = (char)(256 * buffer[2] + buffer[1]);
    chars[1] = (char)(256 * buffer[4] + buffer[3]);
    chars[2] = (char)(256 * buffer[6] + buffer[5]);
    chars[3] = (char)(256 * buffer[8] + buffer[7]);
    chars[4] = (char)(256 * buffer[10] + buffer[9]);

    chars[5] = (char)(256 * buffer[15] + buffer[14]);
    chars[6] = (char)(256 * buffer[17] + buffer[16]);
    chars[7] = (char)(256 * buffer[19] + buffer[18]);
    chars[8] = (char)(256 * buffer[21] + buffer[20]);
    chars[9] = (char)(256 * buffer[23] + buffer[22]);
    chars[10] = (char)(256 * buffer[25] + buffer[24]);

    chars[11] = (char)(256 * buffer[29] + buffer[28]);
    chars[12] = (char)(256 * buffer[31] + buffer[30]);
    string chunk = new string(chars);
    int zero = chunk.IndexOf('\0');
    return zero >= 0 ? chunk.Substring(0, zero) : chunk;
}

private void LoadEntries()
{
    _entries = new Dictionary<long, DirectoryEntry>();
    _freeEntries = new List<long>();

    _selfEntryLocation = -1;
    _parentEntryLocation = -1;

    string lfn = null;  //+++
    while (_dirStream.Position < _dirStream.Length)
    {
        long streamPos = _dirStream.Position;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_fileSystem.FatOptions, _dirStream);

        if (entry.Attributes == (FatAttributes.ReadOnly | FatAttributes.Hidden | FatAttributes.System | FatAttributes.VolumeId))
        {
            // Long File Name entry
            _dirStream.Position = streamPos;  //+++
            lfn = GetLfnChunk(Utilities.ReadFully(_dirStream, 32)) + lfn;  //+++
        }
        else if (entry.Name.IsDeleted())
        {
            // E5 = Free Entry
            _freeEntries.Add(streamPos);
            lfn = null; //+++
        }
        else if (entry.Name == FileName.SelfEntryName)
        {
            _selfEntry = entry;
            _selfEntryLocation = streamPos;
            lfn = null; //+++
        }
        else if (entry.Name == FileName.ParentEntryName)
        {
            _parentEntry = entry;
            _parentEntryLocation = streamPos;
            lfn = null; //+++
        }
        else if (entry.Name == FileName.Null)
        {
            // Free Entry, no more entries available
            _endOfEntries = streamPos;
            lfn = null; //+++
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (lfn != null) //+++
            { //+++
                _lfns.Add(entry.Name.GetDisplayName(_fileSystem.FatOptions.FileNameEncoding), lfn); //+++
            } //+++
            _entries.Add(streamPos, entry);
            lfn = null; //+++
        }
    }
}
```

Second, add these two public functions to the `Fat\FatFileSystem.cs` file. They will be the new APIs to query on LFNs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the long name of a given file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="shortFullPath">The short full path to the file. Input path segments must be short names.</param>
/// <returns>The corresponding long file name.</returns>
public string GetLongFileName(string shortFullPath)
{
    if (shortFullPath == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("shortFullPath");

    string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(shortFullPath);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(shortFullPath);
    Directory dir = GetDirectory(dirPath);
    if (dir == null)
        return fileName;

    string lfn;
    if (dir._lfns.TryGetValue(Path.GetFileName(shortFullPath), out lfn))
        return lfn;

    return fileName;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the long path to a given file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="shortFullPath">The short full path to the file. Input path segments must be short names.</param>
/// <returns>The corresponding long file path to the file or null if not found.</returns>
public string GetLongFilePath(string shortFullPath)
{
    if (shortFullPath == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("shortFullPath");

    string path = null;
    string current = null;
    foreach (string segment in shortFullPath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
    {
        if (current == null)
        {
            current = segment;
            path = GetLongFileName(current);
        }
        else
        {
            current = Path.Combine(current, segment);
            path = Path.Combine(path, GetLongFileName(current));
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

And that's it. Now, youll be able to dump a whole FAT disk recursively like this, for example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open("fat.ima", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (FatFileSystem floppy = new FatFileSystem(fs))
        {
            Dump(floppy.Root);
        }
    }
}

static void Dump(DiscDirectoryInfo di)
{
    foreach (DiscDirectoryInfo subdi in di.GetDirectories())
    {
        Dump(subdi);
    }
    foreach (DiscFileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
        // get LFN name
        Console.WriteLine(" " + ((FatFileSystem)di.FileSystem).GetLongFileName(fi.FullName));


        // get LFN-ed full path
        Console.WriteLine(" " + ((FatFileSystem)di.FileSystem).GetLongFilePath(fi.FullName));
    }
}
```

Use at your own risks! :)

Comment: Were you working on this?? I already decided to edit the `DiscUtils` files once the Bounty Ended! Anyways Thanks! +60 [Bounty + 10(+1)] as soon as the Bounty Ends!

Comment: @WritwickDas - nope, but I found the challenge interesting, and I'm a bounty hunter :-)

Comment: Bounty goes to `Bounty Hunter`!!

Answer (score 2):

[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org) can extract FAT images. There is a C# wrapper library at http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com that can read filenames and extract to streams.

Comment: Are you sure it can extract any type of fat??
Say Fat16 or Fat12...I have a FAT16 file which I tried to open with the Gui but it reported an Error of Invalid Archive...
But I will try...[I know about the SevenZipSharp from before but as 7-Zip itself failed to open the file I did not try that]

Comment: I've used it with floppy images and it has vhd hard disk image support, so I expect it can extract any type of FAT.

Comment: The Exact Error is **"Cannot Open 'FileName' as Archive!"**
Just Checked!
Winimage can edit the Fat that i have, correctly!

Comment: That suggests otherwise indeed. Unfortunately I don't have a FAT16 image available to test. I'm afraid you'll have to find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that there is no Long Name file support for FAT in DiscUtils.  [Check out this post.](http://discutils.codeplex.com/discussions/353129) Which I am sure you are aware of, since it looks like you asked the question.

Comment: You are right, I asked the question there...So I asked here for any alternative i am missing....

Answer (score 1):

The best method with the command line is to use this:

7z "x " + source + " -o" + path + " * -r"

- "x " = Extract; reproduce folder structure
- source = path to disk image
- " -o [path]" = Destination to extract to
- " *" = All files
- " -r" = Recursive

In C#, you can use this method I made (I copied 7z.exe to the Debug folder of my application)

```
public void ExtractDiskImage(string pathToDiskImage, string extractPath, bool WaitForFinish)
{
    ProcessStartInfo UnzipDiskImage = new ProcessStartInfo("7z.exe");
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.Append("x ");
    str.Append(pathToDiskImage);
    str.Append(" -o");
    str.Append(extractPath);
    str.Append(" * -r");
    UnzipDiskImage.Arguments = str.ToString();
    UnzipDiskImage.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process process = Process.Start(UnzipDiskImage);
    if(WaitForFinish == true)
    {
        process.WaitForExit(); //My app had to wait for the extract to finish
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**DOS DIR command with the /X switch displays both long and short names.**

**Otherwise there is a utility to save LFNs: [DOSLFNBk.exe](http://www8.pair.com/dmurdoch/programs/doslfnbk.htm) that would help with creating a mapping table.**

I know not the answers you were looking for but short of manually creating a table first so you can do the mapping without DiskUtil, I can't think of a utility or method to accomplish your aim - but as you mention, here at SO someone might know an alternative.

Kevin from DiskUtils did mention that he would be infringing on a Mirosoft Patent if he included support for LFN's, I am not suggesting you infringe either (DEFINITELY NOT its a commerial project) but if this is just personal or if you can find a library like 7-Zip has the license...

*Your screenshot shows VNext.. same error with RTM versions?*

Comment: What do you mean by _"Your screenshot shows VNext.. same error with RTM versions?"_ I didn't get this sentence...And how can I run the DOS DIR command with the /X switch on a Fat Disc Image??...And AFAIK, `DOS LFN Backup` is not free [I had found this utility before but had no idea of[did not  using it as it wasn't free] and not usable on Disc Image..Anyway Thanks for your suggestions..

Comment: Now checked that DOSLFNBK has a freeware version 1.6 but that version does not support FAT32...Fat32 came in between version 2.0 and 2.3

Comment: vNext == VS 2011, sorry next time I'll put in more researh